# How do I split a string and remove whitespace from the parts?

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to create a console app. The user enters a statement like:

**create** **column** in **table** with values {**Name**, **Address**, **Age**, **Telephone**} **./**

What I am hoping to do is take the line above and create variables:

```
var v1= create;
var v2 = column
var v3 = table;
var v4 = Name;
var v5 = Address;
var v6 = Age;
var v7 = Telepone;
var v8 = ./;
```

So that I can use these values later for conditional statements. I have tried this:

```
string[] split = command.Split(' ',',', '{','}');
```

But it's not giving me what I need; there are white spaces. Does anyone know how I can achieve what I am trying to do? I'm quite new to c# so struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

Add [StringSplitOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] split = command.Split(new char[]{' ',',', '{','}'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the String.Trim method.

```
List<string> parts = command.Split(' ', ',', '{', '}').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
```